# Design a breadcrumb using responsive web design and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I want to have a **breadcrumb** in my page and I want the view be scaled properly with window resizes, resolution changes and code to be device/target independent.

I came to know responsive web design is what I have to do. I have read couple of documents and tutorials and understood that using media queries we can achieve it. So in my media queries I use min-width, max-width to change the css.

What I want to achieve is something more. I have a breadcrumb which looks like below

Link 1 / Link 2 / Link 3 and so on.

Whenever the viewport/screen width is less than 320px I want it to become a dropdown.

Right now I have a solution for that. Create  the default **breadcrumb** and create a dropdown which holds all links and hide it. When ever the width is less than **320px** then I will hide the default breadcrumb and show the dropdown. But this is an odd solution I have at this point of time.

Instead I want some javascript method to act on the default breadcrumb and get all the links from it, then create a dropdown and add all links to it. Then hide the default breadcrumb. For this I have to add a resize handler and fire an event then my javascript will listen to that event and act on the breadcrumb.

Is there any other approach. I do not want to use jquery or any other library because using other libraries is forbidden in our project. We use proprietery libraries.

Any help is greately appreciated. Thank you all.

Comment: Answer updated without using jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Sorry I didn't see that you don't want to use jQuery.

I believe you can use [this](https://gist.github.com/dryan/412126) to convert the links in the breadcrumbs to select element using JavaScript without depending on any library

Code:

```
var nav     =    document.getElementById('nav'),
    links   =    nav.getElementsByTagName('a'),
    select  =    document.createElement('select'),
    option  =    document.createElement('option');

for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++){
    var link    =    links[i],
        _option =    option.cloneNode(false);
    _option.value = link.href; // Set the option's value to the original link
    _option.innerHTML = link.innerHTML; // Set the option's text to the original text 
    // if this link matches the current URL, add a selected attribute
    if( window.location.href == link.href ) {
        _option.selected = 'selected';
    }
    select.appendChild(_option);
};

select.addEventListener('change', function() {
    window.location = select.value;
}, false);

nav.parentNode.insertBefore(select, nav);
nav.style.display = 'none';
```

<s>I have written this jQuery plugin before that convert links in a container into a select element</s>

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.convertToList = function () {
       var that = this;
       this.before(
            $('<select class="breadcrumbs-list"></select>').
            change(function () {
                window.location = $(this).val();
            }
         ))
        this.find('a').each(function () {
            that.prev('select').append('<option value="' + $(this).attr('href') + '">' + $(this).html() + '</option>')
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

You can later use it like `$('.breadcrumbs').convertToList();`

Now use CSS Media queries to hide/show `.breadcrumbs` or `.breadcrumbs-list`

Comment: Yeah I dont want to use jquery but this is a good idea. I need not write the selectbox. Once the page is loaded a javascript method will create a selectbox and populate it with values and hide it. Then I use media queries to hide and display one of the two.